# Problem to use Past Perfect tense (Had met / met)

Tags: tense, past-tense, past-perfect

Sentence:

> It was the first time I had met/met her.

Which tense form should be used, **had met** or **met**?

I have come across this sentence only, not from any specific context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We follow *present* tense by ***Present Perfect*** (indicating *before and up until now*) in contexts like...

> 1: *This **is** the first time I **have [ever] written** this sentence*

But because of preceding ***it was*** in OP's example, we know we're *already* in a "past tense" context. So we need ***Past Perfect*** to refer to an *earlier* state (during which I ***hadn't*** seen her). Hence...

> 2: *It **was** the first time I **had met** her*

Comment: And if the situation is, 'It was the first time they met/had met in the garden', then what could be our choice?

Comment: That's almost identical to my example #2 above (so use Past Perfect). But looking at this answer again now, I have misgivings about my reference to *an **earlier** time during which I **hadn't** seen her*. I don't think there are any contexts where *it was the first time I saw her* is truly "correct", but *That was the **last** time I **saw** him* is definitely okay. Whereas *That was the last time I **had seen** him* is at least "unlikely" (maybe it's okay in certain contexts; I just can't think of one in this current heatwave! :)